# Cant change JS slider to Angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have problem to change my slider into Angular.
Here is my code that works:

```
<div id="main-img" class="main-img">
    <img id="img" src="image.jpg">
</div>
<div id="thumb-img" class="thumb-img" >
    <img src='image.jpg' onclick='changeImage("image.jpg");'>
    <img src='image1.jpg'  onclick='changeImage("image1.jpg");'>
</div>
 <script>
    function changeImage(a) {
        document.getElementById("img").src=a;
    }
</script>
```

And when i need Angular i change it and he is not working:

```
<div id="main-img" class="main-img">
        <img id="img" ng-src="{{some.image1}}">
    </div>
    <div id="thumb-img" class="thumb-img" >
        <img ng-src='{{some.image1}}'  ng-click='changeImage("{{some.image1}}");'>
        <img ng-src='{{some.image2}}'  ng-click='changeImage("{{some.image2}}");'>
     <script>
        function changeImage(a) {
            document.getElementById("img").src=a;
        }
    </script>
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to read up or follow a basic tutorial on Angular. Simply using `ng-src` and `ng-click` isn't how Angular works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-click` is a angular directive that needs the function you are calling `changeimage` to be in scope of that controller. I created an working example from your code you can check here. https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/112/

Basically to "angularize" it you will have to create controller and add the method you want to call on click to its scope.

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('SliderController', ["$scope",function ($scope) {
    $scope.changeImage = function (a) {
       document.getElementById("img").src= a;
    };
}]);
```

**Html:**

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="SliderController">
  <div id="main-img" class="main-img">
    <img id="img" src="image1.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="thumb-img" class="thumb-img">
    <img src='image1.jpg' ng-click='changeImage("image1.jpg");'>
    <img src='image2.jpg' ng-click='changeImage("image2.jpg");'>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This method of simple declaration of a controller via function only (without registering it on the module) is deprecated and will only work in pre-1.3 versions of Angular. With Angular 1.5.x out I think it does the OP a disservice to give an example like this - especially as your JSFiddle references v1.0.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct however point I am trying to get at is to show that the OP is missing a big "concept" in angular, and just replacing onclick with ng-click is not enough.  I will update the answer to be more current though.

Comment: Everything good, but ng-click doesnt works with {{image.someUrl}}, only with images from folder and dont work with images from json =(

Comment: `ng-click` has nothing to do with the images as such. It's up to you on how you want to pass the url to the `changeImage`  function. If it is from json, you will have to pass the object to the function and extract the URL.